# How to access last upgrade date and version in postgres

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

Is there any way i can get information about upgrades, downgrades performed on a postgres 12.3 database  : such as the last upgrade date and version ?
I'm thinking of something that mimicks DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORYin oracle

Comment: No, not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general there are no "patch set" or "service pack" for PostgreSQL but only full releases: every quarter a new release that includes bug fixes is released (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/).

To install these new releases  executables are just replaced as a whole: no patching of current executables is done and this change for related instances and databases is not registered in any system catalog.